# How to rewrite URL in Oracle Content and Experience

Tags: url-rewriting, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How can I rewrite urls in Oracle Content and Experience. I want to rewrite url

`/?categoryId=1`

to

`/1/example`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in the context of an Oracle Content and Experience site you can craft a redirects.json file with redirect rules.  A sample one for your particular example might look like this:

```
{
    "redirectRules": [
        {
            "type": "wildcard",
            "expression": "/?categoryId=*",
            "location": "/site/SampleSite/<$categoryId$>/example"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is more information on this file format [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/content-cloud/creating-experiences/specify-redirect-rules-json-file.html).
Information about uploading this file can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/content-cloud/creating-experiences/add-site-redirect.html).